# EF Core Navigation property on ApplicationUser is always null

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to have a list of "buddies" for an ApplicationUser (just using the standard ASP NET Core Identity implementation).

In my mind, an ApplicationUser can have multiple Buddies, and a Buddy can have multiple ApplicationUser's.  This means its a many to many relationship.

In line with EF Core's existing limitations with M2M relationships, I made a join class that looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationUserBuddies
    {

         public string UserGUID { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
         public string BuddyGUID { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser BuddyUser { get; set; }
    }
```

I then configure ModelBuilder to recognise this relationship with in my OnModelCreating override

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationModels.ApplicationUserBuddies>().HasOne(x => x.ApplicationUser)
            .WithMany(x => x.Buddies).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserGUID).IsRequired();
```

However, when I query through this table using EF, the "buddy" navigation property is always null.  The actual string is set correctly (to that users GUID).  This is how I am getting those details (note I am using Include):

```
var buddies = await _context.ApplicationUserBuddies.Include(x => x.BuddyUser).Where(x => x.UserGUID == UserGUID)
            .Select(x => x.BuddyUser).ToListAsync();
```

Another strange thing is in my ApplicationUserBuddies table, I get a third column that I haven't set up anywhere called BuddyUserID

I think the issue I am having is because I have a many to many relationship that references one table (AspNetUsers table) and that could be affecting it.

How can I have a list of users as a navigation property from AspNetUsers and have it work correctly? Thanks everyone.

**EDIT**

I have changed my model to be in line with EF conventions

```
 public class ApplicationUserBuddies
    {

         public string UserId { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

         public string BuddyUserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser BuddyUser { get; set; }
    }
```

And my model builder now looks like this:

```
     builder.Entity<ApplicationModels.ApplicationUserBuddies>().HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.BuddyUserId });
        builder.Entity<ApplicationModels.ApplicationUserBuddies>().HasOne(x => x.ApplicationUser)
            .WithMany(x => x.Buddies).HasForeignKey(x => x.BuddyUserId).IsRequired();
```

And now I have the columns UserId, BuddyUserId, and the erronerous BuddyUserId1.  I think that this is essentially the same issue that I had at the outset.

Comment: *"Another strange thing is in my ApplicationUserBuddies table, I get a third column that I haven't set up anywhere called BuddyUserID"* This is the root cause of your problem. The column you see is the actual FK associated with the `BuddyUser` navigation property. Since you property names are not following EFC conventions, you had to use something like `HasOne(x => x.BuddyUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.BuddyGUID).IsRequired()` You should check such things in the generated migrations and correct them (in the model) before applying the migration.

Comment: If I wanted to use EF conventions, what would it look like?

Comment: [Foreign Key Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/fk-constraints#conventions). In your case, you already see it - navigation property name "BuddyUser" -> FK name "BuddyUserId".

Comment: @IvanStoev I've changed the classes to EF conventions and I am still getting the duplicate column issue :(.  I feel like I'm missing something really simple.  I've given more details in my edit. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It's not possible to give you a concrete solution w/o seeing the full picture - `ApplicationUser` class (especially navigation proiperties) and relationship configuration. You either have unmapped collection navigation property, or conflicting FK configuration.